# select statement with unions and joins and adding a different field to define row type

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, union

i'm having trouble with a query, it's supposed to get likes, and replies, it got the same kind of fields so i can read them with 1 query which is best for my client side application.. does someone know how i can add a field like the first select statement something like `thisisareply` = 'x' and the second has `thisisareply` = ''

Here's what i currently have:

```
SELECT 
        a.alerts,a.title,r.id as replyid, r.date_added as replydatum,
        u.id as user_id,u.username,u.profile_picture 
    FROM 
        `alerts` a
    LEFT JOIN 
        `reply` r 
        ON 
            a.alerts = r.alert_id 
    LEFT JOIN 
        `users` u 
        ON 
            u.id = r.user_id 
    WHERE 
        a.user_id = '2' 
    GROUP BY 
        replyid 

UNION 

SELECT 
        a.alerts,a.title,i.id as interactionid, i.date_added as likedatum
        ,u.id as user_id,u.username,u.profile_picture 
    FROM 
        `alerts` a 
    LEFT JOIN 
        `interactions` i 
        ON 
            a.alerts = i.alert_id 
    LEFT JOIN 
        `users` u 
        ON 
            u.id = i.user_id 
    WHERE 
        a.user_id = '2' 
    GROUP BY 
        likedatum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can just define your alias `thisisareply` with 'x' and null

```
SELECT 
        a.alerts,a.title,r.id as replyid, r.date_added as replydatum,
        u.id as user_id,u.username,u.profile_picture , 'x' AS thisisareply 
    FROM ....
UNION 
SELECT 
        a.alerts,a.title,i.id as interactionid, i.date_added as likedatum
        ,u.id as user_id,u.username,u.profile_picture, null as thisisareply 
    FROM ...
```

Comment: Personally, I prefer to cast nulls to the correct datatype if other then INT: CONVERT(VARCHAR, NULL). This helps when the upper part of the union is commented out for testing purposes, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 'something' as ReplyType,
    a.alerts,a.title,r.id as replyid, r.date_added as replydatum,
    u.id as user_id,u.username,u.profile_picture 
FROM 
    `alerts` a
LEFT JOIN 
    `reply` r 
    ON 
        a.alerts = r.alert_id 
LEFT JOIN 
    `users` u 
    ON 
        u.id = r.user_id 
WHERE 
    a.user_id = '2' 
GROUP BY 
    replyid 

UNION 

SELECT 'something else' as ReplyType,
    a.alerts,a.title,i.id as interactionid, i.date_added as likedatum
    ,u.id as user_id,u.username,u.profile_picture 
FROM 
    `alerts` a 
LEFT JOIN 
    `interactions` i 
    ON 
        a.alerts = i.alert_id 
LEFT JOIN 
    `users` u 
    ON 
        u.id = i.user_id 
WHERE 
    a.user_id = '2' 
GROUP BY 
    likedatum
```